# isElementPresent is very slow in case if element does not exist.

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

I am using below code to check for element on my web page

```
private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
try {       
      driver.findElement(by);
      return true;
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {       
        return false;
    }

  }
```

I need to check in my program if a particular region appears in result as below

```
isElementPresent(By.xpath(".//*[@id='header']")));
```

If this is present this function completes quickly but if above is not present then it run for very long.

Could some one please help me in resolving this issue so that this check can be performed quickly?

Comment: Try using css locator instead of xpath ?

Comment: Are you using any implicit wait?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Here you are missing somethings that is why it is waiting If there is not element. findElement will wait for an element implicitly specified time. so need to set that time to zero in that method.

```
isElementPresent(WebDriver driver, By by) {  
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
    try {  
        driver.findElement(by);  
        return true;  
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {  
        return false;  
    } finally {  
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);  
    }  
}
```

There are 4 important things going on here. In order:

1. Setting implicity_wait to 0 so that WebDriver does not implicitly wait.
2. Returning True when the element is found.
3. Catching the NoSuchElementException and returning False when we discover that the element is not present instead of stopping the test with an exception.
4. Setting implicitly_wait back to 30 after the action is complete so that WebDriver will implicitly wait in future.

Comment: Thanks it worked with above code. In my case when browser is launched. The url has a form which is posted and it takes a while to get the result back from server so setting timeout value to zero leads to error as element not found.

Comment: Thanks for the hint! " so need to set that time to zero in that method." - caught errors; made setUp for 2 seconds and it began work like a charm for me!

Comment: The latest api has been updated. Use driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(new TimeSpan(0));

Comment: Or in c#, in a more cleaner fashion..
                                                                                                                             
public bool DoesElementExist
        {
            get
            {
                driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
                return driver.FindElements(id_of_element).Count > 0;
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, it's long to send the exception because your DOM is big and the xpath isn't the fastest way to get an element. But if you want to use xpath, try to put the best path and avoid that kind of function where is substring checking.

Your actual xpath : `.//*[@id='header']` takes so long because you check all tags of your DOM. So if put the tag that what you're looking for, example : you want to catch an input. your xpath should start like that `//input[@id='1234']` and it will be shorter than looking all tags.