# selenium (webdriver) - how to check whether a table element exists or not

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I have an html code below. A `<table>` tag is displayed depends on configuration.

```
<div id="test">
    <table id="test2">...</table>
</div>
```

I need to check whether this tag exists or not.

I tried to use findelement operator :

```
Boolean v_evnt2 = Login.driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("#test>#test2")).size() != 0;

If (v_evnt2) 
   System.out.println("tag exist");
else
   System.out.println("tag does not exist);
```

But in case when  is not present then I get an error.

Comment: What kind of error are you getting? I am not seeing any reason

Answer (score 0):

There is no implicit method in WebDriver to check whether element present or not but, you can use below logic.

[isElementPresent is very slow in case if element does not exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075997/iselementpresent-is-very-slow-in-case-if-element-does-not-exist/16079053#16079053)