# Selenium wait until email is sent

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am writing a simple program that tests the functionality of gmail and this include sending an email.

I have the program send an email, and once it is acknowledged that it has been sent, it logs out.

I do not want to logout *while* the message is being sent, only when it is done.

So, if you have gmail and when you send a message you see a little notification above your inbox which says "Your message has been sent. View message."

The cssSelector for that is div.vh.

So I want my program to wait until that window pops up before I log out.

But sometimes it logs out before the message appears due to internet speed.

Here is my code:

```
WebElement element = (new WebDriverWait(driver,10)).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.vh")));
```

Comment: why not just wait longer than 10 seconds?

Comment: It's really not optimal to force a wait like using Thread.sleep(10000);  I should only wait as long as it's required.

Comment: I think what @satnam means is that you are using a 10 second default timeout in your `WebDriverWait`, and if sending the message takes more, then it will stop waiting after 10sec. So why aren't you using a longer default timeout?

Comment: It really doesn't take longer than 10 seconds to send that message, but I'll try your suggestion and do something like 100 seconds,

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After clicking on Send button try to wait until loading text disappear.

```
//Click send
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[text()='Send']")).click();

//wait for element to disappear

waitForElementToDisappear(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading')]"));

or

 //wait for element to appear
waitForElementToAppear(By.id("link_undo"));


    void waitForElementToDisappear(By locator)
    {
                int i=0;
                while(isElementPresent(locator))
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    i++;
                    if(i>50)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
    }

   void waitForElementToAppear(By locator)
    {
                int i=0;
                while(!isElementPresent(locator))
                {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                    i++;
                    if(i>50)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
    }
```

You can find isElementPresent method implementation in below link.

[isElementPresent is very slow in case if element does not exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075997/iselementpresent-is-very-slow-in-case-if-element-does-not-exist)

Comment: both waitForElementToAppear and Disappear implementations are same. If the element appears it has to wait for 5 seconds then break. While loop in appear method should be accompanied by ! . And using Thread.sleep should also be discouraged.

Comment: Thanks Vivek. Yes, I agree. Updated my answer. If you go through implementation of any wait method, it would contain Thread.sleep.

Answer (score 1):

Instead you could have tried something like:

```
WebElement element = null;
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10);
int counter = 0; //optional, just to cut off infinite waiting 
while( element == null && counter != 10 ){
    try{
        element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div.vh")));
    } catch(TimeoutException te) {
        log.info("Not loaded yet, continuing");
        counter++;
    }
}
// logout now.
```