# How to reduce element searching default time in appium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

I have just noticed that Appium & Selenium is taking at least 2 minutes to find element when element is not there.

I want to reduce that time for search.

Code is :

```
 if(!driver.findElements(By.id(AppConstants.notificationcount)).isEmpty())
{

  // DO SOMETHING

}
else
{

   System.out.println("No Element available");    
}
```

Now most of time my element not available so I want appium to check it and redirect quickly to ELSE part , but it is taking long time , Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked your **implicit wait time?**
It is 0 by default, but maybe you are setting it somewhere to a value > 2 mins:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(timeInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

If your implicit wait time is bigger than 0 and you are searching for an element with

```
driver.findElements(...);
```

but *your Element does NOT exist*, then **Selenium will wait the WHOLE specified time!**

Selenium only does not wait, *when at least one element is found*. In this case it will search the page once and return immediately with the list of elements found.

So findElements() is without restriction great to check the existence of an element, but **only good for checking non-existence when you specified a very low implicit wait time** (or the default 0).

If you absolutely need an implicit wait time > 0 for whatever reason, then you can create your own method that handles this like in [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16079053/1943133).

In your case you could set implicit wait time to 0 right before your posted code:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
// then follows your code:
if(!driver.findElements(By.id(AppConstants.notificationcount)).isEmpty())
{

  // DO SOMETHING

}
else
{

   System.out.println("No Element available");    
}
```

If you need an implicit wait time other than 0 elsewhere then just set it back to the original value after your piece of code.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but I want to know that where exactly I should put implicit wait? Because I noticed that once selenium starts to find element , it is not considering wait and searching element for long time.

Comment: as I said in the answer, it depends on how you try to find an element if Java considers the wait time or not in your case since you are using "findElements" you need to set implicitwait to 0 before you are calling this method! -> updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

The quicker way to check is store the elements in a list and then check if it is empty

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.id("AppConstants.notificationcount"));
 if (elements.isEmpty()) {
    System.out.println("No Element available");
        }else{
          elements.get(0).click();//if present click the element
}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes I did this also already , it is working fine but my issue it time it takes to search element. Whenever I use `findelements` , it search element for long time. I want to reduce that search time.