# Speed up .isPresent or .isDisplayed when sometimes expecting false

Tags: java, selenium

I want to check to see if a label exists.  Sometimes I expect it to be displayed "class.checkLabel(true)" and sometimes I want to check to make sure it is hidden "class.checkLabel(false)".  When sending in "false", I am wasting a lot of time waiting for .isPresent to complete.

Is there a way to speed this up besides incorporating WebDriverWait?

```
public void checkLabel(boolean isLabelVisible) {
    boolean result = label.isPresent();
    Assert.assertEquals(isLabelVisible, result);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [isElementPresent is very slow in case if element does not exist.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075997/iselementpresent-is-very-slow-in-case-if-element-does-not-exist)

Comment: You probably have an implicit wait you should get rid of before the findElement. Try the solution in the possible duplicate, if that won't work I'll post another solution.

Comment: Thanks all.  I checked the possible dupe link (I searched, not sure how I missed that one).  @Moshisho - Would like to see your solution too and compare, thanks

Comment: Do you have an implicit wait? anyways, I'd try these solutions if your case is different: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7991522/selenium-webdriver-test-if-element-is-present