# Check if element exists appium C#

Tags: c#, appium

I have made a number of unit tests and I'm running them using appium. When an error pops up I try and capture it by

```
if (PowerPointSession.FindElementByAccessibilityId("CreateErrorIcon").Displayed == true)
{
    exception = "An error occured when creating Agenda/TOC";
    ExceptionHandler(exception);
}
```

This works fine if I have an error and it finds an element called `CreateErrorIcon`. However if no error pops up it seems to get stuck at the beginning of the if statement as if it is checking for an element called `CreateErrorIcon`to be displayed and for some reason it never gets out of the if statement if it doesn't find the element.

Has anyone got any ideas or can point me in the right direction on why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16079053/532575) answers your question.
Basically, `FindElementByAccessibilityId` waits until an element is found or a timeout occurs.

In C# the check would look something like:

```
private static bool IsElementPresent(WindowsDriver<AppiumWebElement> driver, Action findAction)
{
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(TimeSpan.Zero);
    try
    {
        findAction();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
    finally
    {
        driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(GuiTestRunner.Timeout);
    }
}
```

and usage:

```
var isError = IsElementPresent(PowerPointSession, 
    () => PowerPointSession.FindElementByAccessibilityId("CreateErrorIcon"));
if (isError) 
{
    exception = "An error occured when creating Agenda/TOC";
    ExceptionHandler(exception); 
}
```