# Selenium with Python - WebElement.find_element_by_xpath() very slow if element not found

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Using Selenium WebDriver with Python 3.4.

I am writing a scraper, and using the following method to retrieve an element at XPath , relative to a non-root ancestor :

```
def grab_and_clean_selenium(target_path, ancestor_element):
    try:
        target_element = ancestor_element.find_element_by_xpath(target_path)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

This works as expected (and quite quickly) if the elements are located. However, if the element is not located (I am searching for a fair number of optional elements), it seems to take a relatively immense amount of time to process.

For example, the first 10 elements are all present within the page, and are scraped within 0.5 seconds total. Every element that is *not* found takes approximately 1 second, which is increasing the total amount of time for the scraper to run exponentially.

Why is it so costly to search for an element that is not found, and is there any way to reduce this time?

I saw the very similar question at: [isElementPresent is very slow in case if element does not exist.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16075997/iselementpresent-is-very-slow-in-case-if-element-does-not-exist)

However, the accepted solution was to set the implicit wait to 0, which had no impact after setting:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(0)
```

This makes sense, since the implicit wait is already 0 by default.

Any advice?

EDIT: The XPaths in question are:

- ancestor_element: "//a[@style='font-size:18px']"
- target_path: ".//table[@width='450'][2]//tr[1]/td"

Comment: What is your XPath query?

Comment: there is typo in your code: `ancestor_element` != `ancestor`

Comment: Apologies, the typo came in as I was editing, was not present in the actual code. I've fixed it now

Comment: use [findElements_by...](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) instead of `findElement_by....`. These functions return immediately without waiting, However these functions don't wait for element, if it is not present on the page at the checking time, then they return empty set of elements. You must be sure that the page is completely loaded before start checking using this function.